# Looping Through Large KML Text Files

Tags: c#, kml

I am a novice at programming, working on a C# solution for a geomorphology project. I need to extract coordinates from a variable number of Google Earth KML ground overlay files, converted to one long text string, and enter them into an array that can be accessed by other methods.

The KML tags and data of interest look like this:

```
    <LatLonBox>
        <north>37.91904192681665</north>
        <south>37.46543388598137</south>
        <east>15.35832653742206</east>
        <west>14.60128369746704</west>
        <rotation>-0.1556640799496235</rotation>
    </LatLonBox>
```

The text files I will be processing with the program could have between 1 and a 100 or more of these data groups, each embedded within the standard KML file headers/footers and other tags extraneous for my work. I have already developed the method for extracting the coordinate values as strings and have tested it for one KML file.

At this point it seems that the most efficient approach would be to construct some kind of looping method to search through the string for a coordinate data group, extract the data to a row in the array, then continue to the next group. The method might also go through the string and extract all the "north" data to a column in the array first, then loop back for all the "south" data, etc. I am open to any suggestions.

Due to my limited programming background, straight-forward solutions would be preferred over elegant or advanced solutions, but give it your best shot.

Thanks for your help.